# Confused between virtual and override for a property in c#

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual, abstract

I am translating a c++ file to C# and I came across this line of code.

```
public property str1 Headers 
{
    virtual str1 get() override { return headers; }
}
```

So, when I am writing this in C#, how would it be done? Is it a virtual or an overriden property?
This is defined in a class which inherits from a base class that defines this property as an abstract one.

EDIT: I think it's a property in c# and I have translated as follows. But the get method is giving an error.

```
public str1 Headers
{
        override get  { return headers; }
        //virtual get { return headers; }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The modifer override is not valid for this item. Its the same ase if I use a virtual instead of an override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are *overriding* a property inherited from a base class, just use the `override` modifier on your property.
For Properties, the `override` modifier applies to both *get* and *set* accessors.

```
public class YourClass : SomeBaseClass
{
     public override str1 Headers
     {
         get 
         {
              return headers;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. The problem was I was applying override to the accessors instead of the property as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) is used when you *first declare* a property, method, etc. **with an implementation** that can be overridden. [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) is similar, but when you declare it **without** an implementation, so that the deriving class must override it. The syntax for properties is:

```
public abstract class AbsClass1
{
    // non-abstract deriving class MUST override this
    public abstract str1 Headers { get; }
}

public class Class1
{
    // deriving class may override, but doesn't have to
    public virtual str1 Headers { get { return headers; } }
}
```

(that is, it's applied to the whole property, not the `get`)

[`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) is used when you are overriding something that was previously declared as `virtual`. E.g. you might have

```
public class Class2 : AbsClass1
{
    public override str1 Headers { get { return headers; } }
}
```

See also [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) and [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx).

Comment: I've added info on `abstract`

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you need to use use 'virtual' at the top of the inheritance tree, but it doesn't do anything further down, though *by convention* it's used on overriding functions.   There is a hazard in C++ where subtle mismatches of signature cause functions not to act as overrides when you think that they do, and there's no way of the compiler warning you about this.

In C#, these problems were avoided by requiring 'virtual' at the top, and then 'override' on all the overrides below.